# RxSwift how to map to a onComplete event

Tags: rx-swift

I have a `BehaviorSubject<[Int]>`, with the length of the array increasing one at a time. I would like to have an `Observable` that emits a `completed` event when the first element is added to the array, and I don't care about what happens afterwards. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the subscription to your `BehaviorSubject` into your own `Observable` that will call `onCompleted` when the contents of your `BehaviorSubject` change:

```
let array = BehaviorSubject<[Int]>(value: [])

var observable: Observable<Void> {
    return Observable<Void>.create { observer in
    // skip first element as BehaviorSubject repeats last value on subscription
        array.skip(1).subscribe(onNext: { _ in
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
observable.subscribe(onCompleted: {
    print("bump")
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

array.onNext([1]) // now "bump" gets printed
array.onNext([1, 2])
```